# How can I receive the full timeline of a user profile from SEDE?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11786778/nathalie?tab=reputation) is it possible to see the full and detailed actions of timeline. Example: number upvotes, question or answer link/id time received etc?

How is it possible to receive it from SEDE?

Comment: It doesn't have to be possible to achieve the same with SEDE, but there are the Posts, Users, Votes tables. Combined they might give something similar. Have you maybe tried anything?